# Need design guidance to develope java spring hibernate web application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to create java web based application using Spring-Hibernate. I know its not difficult to implement the functionality, but i need some help/guidance from the architecture perspective. Can any one suggest me the best design which will cover interfaces,design patterns etc.

Also need which version should i use of spring and hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to start implementing a web application using the technologies you mentioned is to follow a tutorial from the large variety of tutorials you can find using google.

Another good option is to find a skeleton for an application that someone has created and shared in a source code sharing service like [github](https://github.com) or [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) (check the licenses also). You can check-out the code and have an initial working example you can work on and expand.

If something does not work during these attempts, then please come back here, search if your question is already asked by someone else, and if not place your question with specific code snippets and error messages you may get.

If everything works well and you need advices on different ways to improve performance, your architecture and the software patterns, then come back here also with a specific question, or in some cases you will find [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) more suitable for this kind of questions.

Good luck!